# Knex Raw Select Postgresql with variable

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

Can I use a variable in a knex query? And what is wrong with db.raw(`select usr_vote.vote where usr_vote.user.id = ${loggedInUserId}`)? Everything else works fine.

In the db.raw that is nowt working, I'm trying to use a variable (loggedInUserId) to get the logged-in users' vote history for the Question (they can upvote / downvote so the value is either -1 or 1 or null). Thanks in advance for any help!

There are 4 tables that look like:

**askify_users**

- id
- user_name

**askify_questions**

- id
- title
- body
- tags
- date_created
- user_id (FK references askify_users.id)

**askify_answers**

- id
- answer
- question_id (FK references askify_question.id)
- user_id (FK references askify_users.id)

**askify_question_votes**

- List item
- question_id (FK references askify_questions.id)
- user_id (FK references askify_users.id)
- vote (-1 or 1)
- PRIMARY KEY (question_id, user_id)

```js
getAllQuestions(db, loggedInUserId) {
    return db
      .from('askify_questions AS q')
      .select(
        'q.id AS question_id',
        'q.title AS question_title',
        'q.body AS question_body',
        'q.date_created AS date_created',
        'q.tags',
        db.raw(
          `count(DISTINCT ans) AS number_of_answers`
        ),
        db.raw(
          `SUM(DISTINCT usr_vote.vote) AS sum_of_votes`
        ),
        db.raw(
          `select usr_vote.vote where usr_vote.user_id = ${loggedInUserId}`
        ),
        db.raw(
          `json_strip_nulls(
            json_build_object(
              'user_id', usr.id,
              'user_name', usr.user_name,
              'full_name', usr.full_name,
              'date_created', usr.date_created
            )
          ) AS "user"`
        )
      )
      .leftJoin(
        'askify_answers AS ans',
        'q.id',
        'ans.question_id'
      )
      .leftJoin(
        'askify_users AS usr',
        'q.user_id',
        'usr.id'
      )
      .leftJoin(
        'askify_question_vote AS usr_vote',
        'q.id',
        'usr_vote.question_id'
      )
      .groupBy('q.id', 'usr.id')
  },
```

The query should look as follows. Everything except for 'user_vote_history' is working.

```js
  serializeQuestion(question) {
    const { user } = question
    return {
      id: question.question_id,
      question_title: xss(question.question_title),
      question_body: xss(question.question_body),
      date_created: new Date(question.date_created),
      number_of_answers: Number(question.number_of_answers) || 0,
      user_vote_history: question.user_vote_history,
      sum_of_votes: Number(question.sum_of_votes),
      tags: xss(question.tags),
      user: {
        user_id: user.user_id,
        user_name: user.user_name,
        full_name: user.full_name,
        user_vote: user.user_vote,
        date_created: new Date(user.date_created)
      },
    }
  },
```

Comment: What language are you using? `${loggedInUserId}` seems out-of-place, as javascript variables aren't dollar-prefixed

Comment: Javascript template literal, note the backticks

Comment: **Pay attention** when you use `.raw` with client provided values, you expose your app to SQL injection.

`.raw` accepts second parameter of array with bound values.

Comment: `db.raw(
    'select usr_vote.vote where usr_vote.user_id = ?', [loggedInUserId]
)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I note that [@felixmosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6539317/felixmosh) is correct here regarding bound values, but just to elaborate: the key here is *when the string substitution takes place*. If you do this:

```
db.raw(`SELECT vote WHERE user_id = ${loggedInUserId}`)
```

the substitution takes place in JavaScript, as soon as the JS interpreter reaches this line. The database engine has nothing to do with whatever is in `loggedInUserId` and neither does Knex: you're essentially bypassing all the built-in protections.

Slightly better is:

```
db.raw("SELECT vote WHERE user_id = ?", loggedInUserId)
```

This allows Knex to escape the string in `loggedInUserId`. If you prefer, you can use a named binding:

```
db.raw("SELECT vote WHERE user_id = :loggedInUserId", { loggedInUserId })
```

However, all of this mucking about with bindings is easily avoided by using the facility Knex already provides for subqueries: just put the subquery in a function.

```
db
  .from("askify_questions AS q")
  .select(
    "q.id AS question_id",
    qb => qb.select("usr_vote.vote").where({ user_id: loggedInUserId })
  )
  .leftJoin(
    "askify_question_vote AS usr_vote",
    "q.id",
    "usr_vote.question_id"
  );
```

The `qb` parameter stands for "query builder", and is passed by Knex to your function. It behaves very much like your `db` object.

This generates SQL akin to:

```
SELECT
  "q"."id" AS "question_id",
  (
    SELECT "usr_vote"."user_id" WHERE "user_id" = ?
  ) 
  FROM "askify_questions AS q"
  LEFT JOIN "askify_question_vote" AS "usr_vote"
    ON "q"."id" = "usr_vote"."question_id"
```